# Vs Studio C# Color extension doesn't work for every command

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I change my colors to match the photo with the colored MonoBehavior as it is different when it comes to calling things from other classes, I use the viasfora extention but it seems to not pickup these colors

I would say i have pretty clear colours in general but it seems to not do any thing when it comes to what i mentioned

[image: The colour i want]

[image: my code]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code as it's hard to reproduce the issue then.

Comment: I understand , but my issue is visual rather than with the code it's self